# mysql to div to textarea to mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, tinymce

Sorry my English. I have a query from mysql. I want take to all rows with editable div and 2 different zone which one is NOT NULL Show  (metin, kisametin).

[here](https://plus.google.com/photos/111246015516390297505/albums/6078930686253874801?authkey=CIzC06bUxvixaw)

my code:

```
                  <?php
              $sira = 1;
              $ayarlar = $db->get("bilgiler", NULL, "adi, link, metin, kisametin, IF( metin IS NOT NULL, 'metin', IF( kisametin IS NOT NULL, 'kisametin', NULL ) ) AS olan");
              if( $db->count > 0 ){
                foreach($ayarlar as $ayar){
              ?>                  
                  <form method='GET'>
                    <?=( $sira%2 == 0 )?"<tr class='success'>":"<tr>"?>
                      <td><?=$sira?></td>
                      <td><?=$ayar[link]?></td>
                      <td>
                      <?php
                      if($ayar[olan] == "kisametin"){
                          echo "<div class='kisametin'><div id='veri' name='veri' >".$ayar["kisametin"]."</div></div>";
                          echo "<input type='hidden' id='veri_hidden' name='veri'/>";
                      }
                      if($ayar[olan] == "metin"){
                          echo "<div class='metin'><div id='veri' name='veri' >".$ayar["metin"]."</div></div>";
                          echo "<textarea hidden id='veri_hidden' name='veri'></textarea>";
                      }
                      ?></td>
                      <input type='hidden' name='adi' value='<?=$ayar[adi]?>' />
                      <input type='hidden' name='olan' value='<?=$ayar[olan]?>' />

                      <td><button class='btn btn-default'>&gt;&gt;&gt;</button></td>
                    </tr>
                  </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                setInterval(function () {
                  document.getElementById("veri_hidden").value = document.getElementById("veri").innerHTML;
                }, 15);
                </script>                                   
              <?php   
                $sira++;
                }
              }
              ?>
```

when I submit only first row is change, other rows editable but when I submit not save. my update function is

```
if( $_POST ){

if( $_POST[veri] != bilgi($_POST[adi],$_POST[olan]) ){
    $db->where("adi", $_POST[adi]);
    if($db->update("bilgiler", Array( $_POST[olan] => $_POST[veri] ) ));
}
```

}

Any idea please

Comment: picture does not work

Comment: "picture does not work" ok

Comment: You are generating multiple forms within the same page, therefore submitting one of them will only contain data from the input fields within that form

Comment: when i submit not work only first record is work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with your JavaScript : you make multiple forms but your js,

```
document.getElementById("veri_hidden").value = document.getElementById("veri").innerHTML;
```

only gets first elements with id 'veri_hidden' and 'veri'.

off-course you shouldn't let multiple html elements have same id.